# K99 stop order in pure systemd unit

Tags: systemd

I need to run a script on shutdown, reboot or `systemctl isolate rescue.target` or `init 1`. I have some `sysv` init scripts (my OS is `Centos7`). My script should run after all these scripts stopped. Their names are generated, so I can't use them in my `WantedBy` option.

I didn't want to list all possible shutdown variants in `WantedBy` and thought that it would be simpler to run my script using `ExecStop` instead of `ExecStart`.

I tried `WantedBy=basic.target`, assuming it would stop later than units reqired by `multi-user.target`, but this didn't work:

```
# my unit stopped:
Apr 08 16:58:00 wc8rh7 systemd[1]: Stopped Stop all db2 processes except fault monitor.
# the generated sysv script stopped:
Apr 08 16:58:12 wc8rh7 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts and stops Application Server instances.
```

_

```
[Unit]
Description=Stop all db2 processes except fault monitor
#DefaultDependencies=no
#Before=multi-user.target

[Service]
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/db2stopall
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```